How do you achieve isolation in ACID transactions?
what is a concrete implementation I can use for isolating transactions? For example, for atomicity, I can lump multiple statements underneath a BEGIN TRAN and then call COMMIT somewhere down the line. For consistency, I can set types for columns as well as constraints. For durability, I can set a trigger to archive records onto another table, schedule backup jobs or manually back records up myself. What can I do for isolation? Is locking a table a way to achieve this? Do I need to understand what a database "session" is for me to make sense of isolation?

BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT covers all of ACID, the other things that you mention are irrelevant. Consistency, durability and isolation are to do with transaction anomalies, nothing to do with data types, auditing and backup. Locking is automatic anyway.

Automatic locking? Locking isn't always needed, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Every transaction, not only exlicit ones (eg those between BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT/ROLLBACK) are isolated from other sessions/users.
Locks are sets automatically by the storage engine at the finest "surface" they can :

mode : shared for reads, exclusive for writes
granularity : row, page, partition, table/index, depending of the
amount of data used by the transaction
type : pessimistic or optimistic
duration : the statement or the transaction depending of the
TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL used

TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL can have 4 levels :

READ UNCOMMITTED : able to read uncommitted values (dirty read,
chaos... - no lock)
READ COMMITTED (the ordinary level for pessimistc mode) : reading
only committed values (lock duration is the statement)
REPEATBLE READ : the same dataset has always the sames values when
reading twice or more during the transaction. Locks on rows are
maintened to the end (COMMIT/ROLLBACK)
SERIALIZABLE : the tables is locked to encure no UPDATE nor INSERTs
during the transaction such as new row won't modify the global value
of the dataset

The higher the isolation level you choose, the less concurrency there will be.
Any SQL command you execute that modify the structure or read or write the data, even those like CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, REVOKE, EXECUTE... is an explicit transaction by default...

"even those like CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, REVOKE, EXECUTE... is an exeplicit transaction by default..." Except in MySQL as usual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Yes but it is specific to MySQL and SQlite do the same.... Not enterprise database...
